# How to create new task list each time workflow runs

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, tasks, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

I have  a master project management list. When a new item is added to this list, I want to create a task list with about a dozen tasks.

When another item is added to the original list, I want to create a new task list with the same tasks as the first.

How do I ensure that each item added to the master list creates a new task list? Currently, each time the workflow runs all the tasks are added to the same task list instead of different ones.

Here is my logic to create the tasks:
[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Creating new task lists will be somewhat tricky. In theory, you could do all of this via web service calls. But as an alternative, I'd suggest adding a column to one task list that identifies which "category" of task it belongs to. So each time you add the dozen tasks,  they'd all go to the same list, but all dozen would have the same value in the "category" field. You could then create a grouped and/or filtered view on the list so that users could easily find the tasks that pertain to them.